# raspberry pi unable to install lxml pip package

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, raspberry-pi, pip, lxml

I am trying to install `lxml` package after i installed `BeautifulSoup4` package.

In the terminal i type:

```
sudo pip install lxml
```

This is what i get

```
sudo pip install lxml
Downloading/unpacking lxml
  Running setup.py egg_info for package lxml
    Building lxml version 3.6.1.
    Building without Cython.
    Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.26
    Building against libxml2/libxslt in the following directory: /usr/lib

Installing collected packages: lxml
  Running setup.py install for lxml
    Building lxml version 3.6.1.
    Building without Cython.
    Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.26
    Building against libxml2/libxslt in the following directory: /usr/lib
    building 'lxml.etree' extension
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/libxml2 -Isrc/lxml/includes -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/lxml/lxml.etree.c -o build/temp.linux-armv9l-2.7/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -w
```

And then it just hangs there at the last line for a very long long time, I have to exit by pressing <kbd>CTRL+C</kbd>.

Can someone tell me what it really means?

I then try `pip freeze` to see if the package is installed. No, it is not there.

Comment: It means you are on a device where the hardware is pretty limited so compiling programs can take a very long time. If you exit in the middle of compiling it is not exactly a surprise that it does not get installed.

Comment: On my Raspberry Pi the compiler crashed saying: "arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1)" Maybe due to lack of memory, I don't know (yet).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

well you could open python and try importing it. But if its python 3 try this

```
sudo apt-get install python3-lxml
```

else its

```
sudo apt-get install python-lxml
```

Comment: My raspberry pi was freezing when I used `pip` to install `lxml` but after doing it with `apt-get` it worked. Thank you very much :)